# How to display shops near by user

Tags: location

I am creating a website in which I want to show the similar shops near by user location.

Like if a user selects `Bangalore -> M.G. Road` then the similar shops near by `M.G. Road` should be displayed.

However, I don't want to use *Google Maps*, because it will take too long to open.

Any suggestions about how I can do this in Drupal7?

Answer (score 0):

Using [Google Store Locator](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_store_locator) module you can solve your query.

> This project uses Google's Store Locator Utility Library and Google
>   Maps to create a 'Store Locator' page that your site visitors can use
>   to find and get directions to one of your physical stores. It was born
>   out of a need for a simple to install and easy to use locator feature
>   for Drupal 7. This module is different from other 'locator' type
>   modules (e.g. OpenLayers Locator) in that it doesn't require you to
>   have any knowledge of it's dependant modules, and it allows developers
>   to focus on implementing personal customizations quickly because the
>   installation process is so light.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [location](https://www.drupal.org/project/location) module to store your addresses, then you can filter or sort by proximity / distance in views.